AC not working properly
I have a 2017 Ford Escape and the air conditioner only blows cold at night. I did take my truck to a mechanic and they informed me it would be $1,700 to fix because the compressor is bad.  is there any other option that doesn't cost as much??? it blows ice cold at night or when its raining outside.
thanks

If you are not comfortable with the first mechanic, consider to visit a second one. If the answer is the same, that the compressor is bad, you may get a different price.

Let's make that a very strong recommendation to get a second opinion. Believe it or not, there are a few dishonest mechanics who would lie to someone unfamiliar with auto repair and tell them they need a $1700 compressor when they know full well that all they need is a recharge costing $150 to $300 including labor to check for leaks. What a shame. We can't know from here what's wrong with your car, but a second and/or third opinion is mandatory if you don't know auto repair.
